Error: An internal server error has occurred 1414871719-51886 (-265281356) when trying to delete or rename Messaging Channel Parameter
We have created a Messaging Channel Parameter with a wrong name and we are not able to rename or delete Messaging Channel Parameter.
I have seen an idea opened https://ideas.salesforce.com/s/idea/a0B8W00000NVWsTUAX/let-userssalesforce-support-delete-messaging-channels claiming that it is not possible to delete MessagingChannel even for Salesforce Support, can we at least rename or delete Messaging Channel Parameter?
When I try to delete it from UI, I see no error but in Javascript Console Log I can find
internal gack id

Error: An internal server error has occurred
Error ID: 1414871719-51886 (-265281356)

When I try to perform the deployment, error message is shown


Messaging Channel Parameter User_Id can't be deleted as it is
referenced elsewhere.

but it is not mentioned where exactly this is being used
This is old metadata
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<MessagingChannel xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <customParameters>
        <externalParameterName>User_Id</externalParameterName>
        <masterLabel>User Id</masterLabel>
        <maxLength>18</maxLength>
        <name>User_Id</name>
        <parameterDataType>String</parameterDataType>
    </customParameters>
    <masterLabel>Web</masterLabel>
    <messagingChannelType>EmbeddedMessaging</messagingChannelType>
    <sessionHandlerFlow>RoutetoBot</sessionHandlerFlow>
    <sessionHandlerQueue>Queue</sessionHandlerQueue>
    <sessionHandlerType>Flow</sessionHandlerType>
</MessagingChannel>

and new metadata
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<MessagingChannel xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <customParameters>
        <actionParameterMappings>
            <actionParameterName>UserId</actionParameterName>
        </actionParameterMappings>
        <externalParameterName>UserId</externalParameterName>
        <masterLabel>UserId</masterLabel>
        <maxLength>18</maxLength>
        <name>UserId</name>
        <parameterDataType>String</parameterDataType>
    </customParameters>    
    <masterLabel>Web</masterLabel>
    <messagingChannelType>EmbeddedMessaging</messagingChannelType>
    <sessionHandlerFlow>RoutetoBot</sessionHandlerFlow>
    <sessionHandlerQueue>Queue</sessionHandlerQueue>
    <sessionHandlerType>Flow</sessionHandlerType>
</MessagingChannel>


On Embedded Service Deployment in Hidden Pre-Chat Fields, we had to unselect User_Id from Seelcted list and move it to Available list to resolve the dependency.

Looks like https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_embeddedserviceconfig.htm EmbeddedServiceConfig doesn't include currently  which pre-chat fields are selected and which are not, so we are not able to automate deployment of these configuration and have to do this manually before or after deployment to fix errors
Update:
SF Support confirmed this is a Bug on their side but they didn't provide any known issue link to subscribe and no ETA for a fix.
